# Automatic sending of windows to virtual Desktop 2 in plasma

Tags: kde, plasma, virtualdesktop

In KDE environment, I want every LibreOffice document, when opened, to go automatically to virtual Desktop 2 and every Chromium window be on Desktop 1 (wherever they are opened).

Is there a way to make this automatic?

Comment: you can check out kwin's configuration. in compiz, there's a configuration to fix a specific program on a certain desktop.i don't know if kwin also support this.

Answer (score 4):

```
System settings --> Windows Behavior --> Window Rules -->
1)  Window Matching --> 
    1.1) Windows Class --> Substring Match --> libreoffice
    1.2) Windows Title --> Regular Expression --> Writer
2)  Size and Position --> Desktop --> Force --> Desktop 2
```

Comment: just to archive a method.